# Why could early displays not show white colours?

Tags: display, history

They were usually seen using green or orange text, but apparently because white was not possible for some reason?

Comment: What type of displays are you talking about? CRT (cathode-ray tube), LED, LCD, electroluminescent, nixie tubes, ...? What has your research taught you?

Comment: If you mean computer displays, there were screens that used white.  Amber and green caused less eye strain, though, so professional equipment used those colors instead.

Comment: B/W CRTs existed from the very beginning.

Comment: I think the OP is discussing the time period circa when the Plato terminals existed. See [Plato](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PLATO_(computer_system)), where you will see examples of both orange and green -- the ONLY possible colors at that time. Bitzer invented those plasma things, I believe.

Comment: They were NOT the only possible colors.  They chose to use green or amber for PLATO.  White was available at the time, as millions of black and white TVs can witness.

Comment: There was no real “choice” for PLATO.  The plasma pixels were only available in that orange when the project started.

Answer (score 2):

Early orange and green displays came from different backgrounds, with different purposes.

The early green CRTs used green light because of ergonomics of business applications: The green phosphors of the time had long decay times, so they didn't flicker even with slow refresh rates. That made them easier on the eyes when a user was looking at them from close quarters for a large part of the working day. This was even part of the advertising for the [IBM 3270 displays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_3270).

The orange displays were plasma screens for educational applications, which could do (rudimentary) animation and graphics better than CRTs at the that time.   The [PLATO system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PLATO_(computer_system)) really drove [development of those plasma displays](http://www.ozsportshistory.com/cda/platoplasma.html), and they became really well known in the early '70's  for their interactivity and resulting student engagement.

Comment: Not all green phosphors had long decay times.  Green phosphors were use in oscilloscopes.  The decay time can't be too long else you would only see a green smear with the faster timebase settings.

Comment: @jre Not sure whether ‘scopes used the same green phosphor or not.  I’m a little color blind, and the typical Tek or HP trace looked whiter (less toward yellow) to me. For a ‘scope, the persistence had to be long enough that e.g. alt-sweep mode would work well, but fast enough to be responsive. Sub-second, but faster than 30-Hz was generally a sweet spot. It let you do things like this:  https://goo.gl/images/jupkiW

Answer (score 1):

I'm not completely sure, but it seems to be about efficiency.

[CRTs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cathode_ray_tube)-based [Monochrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monochrome_monitor) monitors  work by having the inside of the vacuum tube painted with a [phosphor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phosphor) which glows when hit by an electron beam.

Since the cost of the high voltage supply will depend on its power, it makes sense to use an efficient phosphor, in other words one which will produce the brightest image (as perceived by the human eye) for a given electrical power.

The human eye has peak sensitivity at 555nm (green). See the [function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luminosity_function) that is used to convert light power into lumens (the lumen unit is weighted by the human sensitivity function, so higher lumens are brighter regardless of wavelength).

[This paper](http://www.hep.ph.ic.ac.uk/fets/pepperpot/docs+papers/EA_116.pdf) lists the luminous efficacy of various phosphors, in lumen per watt. Green is 3x better than red and blue, which seems to be mostly due to the eye having higher sensitivity.

Getting a white color requires a white phosphor, which is a mix of several phosphors of different colors. This has lower luminous efficacy than green, as power has to be spent to create red and blue light, to which the eye is a lot less sensitive.

So, my guess would be that the choice of green color is simply due to cost optimization, as it requires a lower power high voltage system.

Comment: Not so much a problem, I would think.  There were black and white TVs for decades before computer monitors were a thing.  And, efficiency wasn't as big a deal back then.

Answer (score 0):

I think it was purely fashion.

There were green screens, then there were white then it was green again, then it was orange. There were polarisers, and fingerprint enhancers and negative thought field filtering glass. There were even plastic rainbow filters for a bit, because you are happier looking at sunsets apparently. (whilst approving arrest warrants, mortgage foreclosures, turning down cancer therapy or whatever you were doing on your terminal)

There are screens which match your "retina". There are wide-short screens because letterbox slots are narrow, so that is how we want to read documents.

Each if them had some B.S. justification for why it was better that last years colour.

[though frankly, they look like rank amateurs compared to todays marketers, who can say with a straight face that Glass, the most slippery and breakable material known to man is just the *perfect* thing to make the back of your phone out of]

Answer (score -3):

If it is LED display, then before 1990 there was no BLUE LED and that's why it was not possible to display WHITE text. To display white light there is a need for proper mixing of RED, GREEN and BLUE. So, the invention of BLUE LED makes it possible to display white light.
you can check the following link that how blue light is emitted.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_ZmTRb_vzFRLRCUYQxeoOwCp1Juws8kq/view

Comment: Monitors in early 1990s didn't use LEDs in the display, so it didn't matter that there were no blue LEDs.  CRT monitors at the time were capable of displaying colors - including white.  Liquid crystal displays at the time were monochrome, and came in various combinations (black on green, blue on gray, etc.)